# Placing text along node shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to place text along the shape of a node. The MWE below generates the following image.  I'd like the text 'Classic First Program' to follow the circle of the node shape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node [label=above:Classic First Program, align=center,circle,font=\huge,draw] {Hello\\ World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there an automated way to do this without self-defining another path that matches the node shape? I'd like to be able to change the interior text (and hence the node shape) without also having to adjust the label text.

Comment: Will the node always be circular, or are other shapes possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe there is an easy way, but I could not find it.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
circle, 
draw,
align=center,
font=\huge,
decoration={text along path, text align=center, reverse path=true, text={Classic First Program}},
postaction={decorate}, 
rotate=-90,
]  {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Hello}\,\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{World!}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle with text inside and along top]

Edit: An alternative way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
circle, 
draw,
align=center,
font=\huge,
text opacity=0,
decoration={text along path, text align=center, reverse path=true, text={Classic First Program}},
postaction={decorate}, 
rotate=-90,
label={[align=center, font=\huge]center:Hello\\World!},
]  {Hello\\World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle with text inside and along top]

**Edit: I did it :o)**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
circle, 
draw,
align=center,
font=\huge,
decoration={text along path, text align=center, reverse path=true, text={Classic First Program}},
postaction={transform canvas={rotate=-90}, postaction={decorate}}, 
]  {Hello\\World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The last solution breaks when using `at`, such as `\node at (0,1) [circle ...`. I can't figure out why, nor how to adjust for it. I suspect it is related to the `transform canvas` part. Any suggestions?

Comment: @GregH: Yes it needs to rotate around the same point (default is `(0,0)`). Replace  `rotate=-90` with `rotate around={-90:(2,3)}` where `(2,3)` is the same coordinate as the `at` placement.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @hpekristiansen's last answer above:

[image]

I added a `decoration={raise=3pt}` to place the text a bit off the path (and changed the angle at which it is centered).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
circle, 
draw,
align=center,
font=\huge,
decoration={text along path, text align=center, reverse path=true, text={Classic First Program}},
postaction={transform canvas={rotate=-45}, postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=3pt}}}, 
]  {Hello\\World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```